# Build failure after adding dependency quarkus-resteasy-reactive

Tags: maven, pom.xml, quarkus

It seems like I got dependency conflict by adding these dependencies to my quarkus-app

```
mvn quarkus:add-extension -Dextension="quarkus-resteasy-jsonb, quarkus-jdbc-h2, quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache, quarkus-smallrye-openapi"
```

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CapabilityAggregationStep#aggregateCapabilities threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please make sure there is only one provider of the following capabilities:
capability io.quarkus.rest is provided by:
  - io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive:2.8.1.Final
  - io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:2.8.1.Final
```

That's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.redhat.developers</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutorial-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <failsafe.useModulePath>false</failsafe.useModulePath>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.8.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I couldn't find anything about resolving this issue, maybe you could correct dependencies or explain me, why it gets such a conflict. I can't see **quarkus-resteasy** in my pom.xml, but I think that it's the conflict between **quarkus-resteasy-jsonb** and **quarkus-resteasy-reactive**, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. Instead of `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb`, use `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb`.

In general, classic RESTEasy and RESTEasy Reactive can't be used together. And it makes no sense, they are two different implementations of the same API (more or less, there are *some* subtle differences).